# Getting weird characters in hyper-terminal on serial connection of PC and Atmega-16

Tags: serial, atmega, max232, error

I have a Atmega-16 based board, connected via Max232 to pins 2,3,5 of a db-9 connector. The connector connects to a PC.
I am getting weird characters on hyper-terminal instead of normal "Hello World" for the serial test program. I have set both baud rate in Atmega-16 as well as hyper terminal to be 4800.
I am not getting any faults. Please help.
Thank you!

Edit: I am using this kit : http://roboshop.nextsapiens.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=55
The Serial pins of the Atmega16 are routed through a max232 to db-9, the circuit is same as this one:

[image]

The settings on terminal are:

Data bits: 8
Stop bits: 1
Parity: none
Baud rate: 4800

The bascom code is:

```
$regfile = "m16def.dat"
$crystal = 2000000
$baud = 9600
Config Lcd = 16 * 2
Config Lcdpin = Pin

Cls

Cursor Off

Dim A As String * 1
Do
  A = Waitkey()
  Print A
  Cls
  Lcd A
Loop

End
```

The problem can further be viewed as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmnJo.png

The images showing the characters(10) i am receiving are:
[image]

and the corresponding hex code that i am reciving is:

[image]

Comment: Make sure the polarity of the signal is correct, as the Max232 inverts it if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Oli - Yes, but that's a property of RS232: logic 1 = -12 V, logic 0 = +12 V. the receiver should invert it again.

Comment: @Steven - I know, but I was thinking the OP may have set the UART up with logic 0 = +5V already, so when passed through the Max232 it ends up with logic 0 = -12V. Many uC UART peripherals have a polarity selection bit.

Comment: Have you tried using [TeraTerm](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/ttssh2/)? I've had better luck with that (HyperTerminal tends to be *too* automated).

Comment: @Oli -They do??? Looks pretty much like asking for problems. I've never seen any that allows that, by the way.

Comment: @Steven - I should have said "some" rather than "many". Some PICs like the PIC24 have RX/TX invert polarity bits if I remember right. Also it's possible the OP is bit banging. Been a long time since I used a Max232...

Comment: @user636177 can you post a (link to) schematic please? Are you connecting the hardware UART of the ATMega16 to the MAX232?

Comment: Can we see the initialization code for the Atmega USART and the frame definition in Hyper Terminal (number of start/stop bits, number of data bits, parity)?

Comment: Post a schematic with your exact setup and relavent code for proper help. As it is now is kind of a waste time with people guessing

Comment: I have edited the post to include more info..

Comment: @user636177 you have not posted the ATMEGA portion of the schematic though.  I'd particularly like to know about your clock source.  Are you really running it at 2 MHz??

Comment: @chris I am running it at 2 MHz, using the Rx and Tx ports as referred from :  http://datasheetreference.com/images/atmega16_pinouts.png

Comment: @user636177 - looking at the product link, I can't see any documentation but I think the board uses a 16MHz crystal. Try setting `$crystal = 16000000` in your code.

Comment: @oli tried 16 Mhz, doesn't work either, I got this while surfing the net, but the real problem isn't even solved here: http://www.societyofrobots.com/robotforum/index.php?topic=15415.0

Comment: What pattern of characters do you get? (this is important as it gives us a clue) Also try setting to 8000000. Can you link to a picture of the results as you have with the other one.

Comment: @OliGlaser i have included the characters i am receiving in question. They should have been "1 0" instead of the long weird strings i am getting.

Comment: @user636177 - hard to make out the characters. How many times did you send 1 and 0 here? It's almost certainly a baud rate issue (possibly hyperterminal settings), and probably related to your crystal/clock divider setup. The variable will be used to calculate the clock divider for the baud rate. You need to work thrpugh and make absolutely sure you know what the system clock is running at, then find the macro that calculates the baud rate. I don't use AVR though so I'm not sure of the fuse settings, maybe someone else can help there.

Comment: The 1 and 0 were sent 3 times for the character image and one time for hex code image. I am working on baud rate correction, will update in few hours

Comment: You might consider doing a direct readback of the hardware baud rate registers (if that is supported?), and comparing to the data sheet values. Alternatively, you could do a direct overwrite (post initialization) with believed correct values.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved after using a different baud rate on the hyper-terminal ,viz. 4800 while the microcontrollere running on 9600 and 2 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Check the baud rate on the hyper terminal or the oscillator settings.

Comment: I have already checked them, and its fine, some other problem is there

Comment: @user636177 If you have access to a oscilloscope try to check that the correct data is being transmitted.

Comment: Either measure the actual baud rate (inverse of the period of the shortest pulses) or verify that the baud divisors are being correctly set **for the clock actually in use** on the board.  Also, the ATMEGA family has an additional divide-by-two bit in another register.

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively unlikely that the 2 MHz clock frequency given in your code is appropriate.  More likely candidates would be 12 or 16 MHz, or even 8 MHz.

If you cannot determine the actual crystal frequency, you could "measure" it by figuring out the number of bit periods per byte of transmitted data (iirc 10, but check that) and diving your chosen baud rate by that to find the number of bytes per second.  Multiply that by say 5 and write a for loop to turn on an LED, send that many bytes, then turn it off.  Time how long it takes.

Comment: The clock operates at a frequency of 8 MHz, but has to be scaled down to 2 MHz for proper functioning of the serial communication as told by manufacturer of kit. Is the variable type a problem?

Comment: That statement is hard to find credible; if anything, the higher the clock rate the more precisely you can generate a UART baud rate.  Likely the message has been confused somewhere along the way, or the concern has to do with something unrelated to the UART.  Try the timing experiment.

Comment: The data sheet http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2466.pdf includes baud divisor tables all the way up to 20 MHz clock.

Comment: i tried timing experiment, through LEDs and the baud rate seems correct. Please see this http://www.apsim.info/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=APSIM-and-the-APSIM-Initiative&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 .

Comment: @user636177 The relevance of your link isn't immediately apparent.  I take it you do not have an oscilloscope?   How about dropping the baud rate to maybe 1200 baud, sending one character over and over (0x55, 'U' would be a good choice for its bit pattern) and coupling the serial line into your sound card and plotting the data?  It might take a little experimentation with resistive dividers to get a good picture, but in theory your should have 48 KHz/1200 Hz = 40 samples per bit.  You could also set your PC serial port to output the same thing and compare how that looks.

Comment: Thanks but i already tried with LEDs at a low baud rate and continuous strings of 255s and 0s and it was correct. BTW the problem was solved at setting hyper-terminal baud to 4800 and kit baud to 9600. I will keep your suggestion in my mind for further problems if they arise.

Comment: If that was the solution, it means your oscillator value in the baud rate calculation in wrong!  You should change that, so that the baud rate in the code matches reality.